# VS 2019 Cant Find GitHub Repo

Tags: git, visual-studio, repository, fatal-error

I am trying to clone the following repo:

https://github.com/3b1b/videos/tree/master/_2022/wordle

I have cleared the windows credentials, changed my git settings in VS and tried it from the command line with no luck. It throws the "fatal error repository not found" error every time. I don't know tons about how git interacts with VS etc. so please walk me through each step or point me to another solution. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: The url you are providing is not the one of a github repository. The good url is `https://github.com/3b1b/videos.git`

Answer (score 0):

The url you are providing is not the one of a github repository. The good url is https://github.com/3b1b/videos.git

[image: clone url]

Comment: I knew I was dumb but wow lol. Thanks brotha!